# Android development RecoverySystem.installPackage() cannot write to /cache/recovery/command permission denied

Tags: android

I have been asked to write a small simple app for an Android-based product. The device comes with two Android system images with different features. The app I'm writing is just a proof of concept where when you click on a button, it uses the Recovery System to replace the current OS with one of the images.

The device is rooted and the application runs as a system app.

I use

```
RecoverySystem.installPackage(context, packageFile);
```

([see here for reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/RecoverySystem.html#installPackage%28android.content.Context,%20java.io.File%29)) to replace the OS with one of the images. This should reboot the system and initialize the recovery system to install the image.

The problem that I have is that this call fails because the `RecoverySystem.installPackage` method can't seem to access the /cache/recovery/command file. I guess it tries to write some commands for the recovery system to be executed on reboot, but fails. Here is the exception I am getting:

```
02-27 16:44:39.463: E/BroadSign Resolution Switcher(4439): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /cache/recovery/command: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
02-27 16:44:39.463: E/BroadSign Resolution Switcher(4439):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:416)
02-27 16:44:39.463: E/BroadSign Resolution Switcher(4439):  at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
02-27 16:44:39.463: E/BroadSign Resolution Switcher(4439):  at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:73)
02-27 16:44:39.463: E/BroadSign Resolution Switcher(4439):  at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:42)
02-27 16:44:39.463: E/BroadSign Resolution Switcher(4439):  at android.os.RecoverySystem.bootCommand(RecoverySystem.java:381)
02-27 16:44:39.463: E/BroadSign Resolution Switcher(4439):  at android.os.RecoverySystem.installPackage(RecoverySystem.java:330)
```

So, I am assuming that I don't have the proper permission to access this file. Though here are the permission that I have set in my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REBOOT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_CACHE_FILESYSTEM" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DELETE_CACHE_FILES" />
```

I know I need the REBOOT permission for the `RecoverySystem`. However, I don't know if the other two are relevant. I don't even know if I need some other permission to create/write to files in the /cache partition.

Does anybody know what I could be missing?

---

**UPDATE:**

Well, it looks like I figured it out. The permissions were right after all. Everything was right.

When I was setting up the app as a system app by moving the apk file to /system/app I hadn't put all the permissions in yet. When I ran the latest code on my device, it installed it in /data/app and recognized it as an update to the system app. Because of that, only the permissions of the original system app were recognized.

After I re-set up my latest code to run from /system/app directly, it worked.

Now the only issue I have is that when it reboots it doesn't install the image and I end up with a dead green robot with an exclamation mark. I'll keep investigating.

I hope this post helps anyone with the same issue. I'll be happy to answer any questions as well.

Comment: I did the same and I am able to run FOTA upgrade. But my problem is that, the app which I made has a label as platform_app, and the app used by google for upgrade falls in untrusted_app. Is there any way to make my app as untrusted_app with above cache permissions intact, because these permissions are given only to system apps I guess

Comment: @PankajKushwaha Hi pankaj i am also trying to implement FOTA in my aap programitically . The [link](http://shriduttkothari.blogspot.in/2013/08/fota-in-android-mechanism.html) i found some sol but i cannot understand how to proceed further with this.

Comment: I will tell you the basic procedure which I have followed-
1) run make otapackage. Lets name it update.zip
2) copy the zip file in /cache/recovery/update.zip
3) write the following command "--update_package=/cache/update.zip" in /cache/recovery/command
4) Reboot device in recovery mode.
5) Device will automatically get upgraded.

You can find sample code in /frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/RecoverySystem.java

The app which I use is a sytem app (signed with platform key)

Answer (score 2):

Before when my app was installed in /system/app I was getting below error:

```
07-20 10:52:46.512      933-951/? W/RecoverySystem﹕ !!! REBOOTING TO INSTALL /storage/emulated/legacy/Download/Update.zip !!!
07-20 10:52:46.512      933-951/? W/System.err﹕ java.io.FileNotFoundException: /cache/recovery/command: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
07-20 10:52:46.512      933-951/? W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
07-20 10:52:46.512      933-951/? W/System.err﹕ at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
07-20 10:52:46.512      933-951/? W/System.err﹕ at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:73)
07-20 10:52:46.512      933-951/? W/System.err﹕ at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:42)
07-20 10:52:46.512      933-951/? W/System.err﹕ at android.os.RecoverySystem.bootCommand(RecoverySystem.java:389)
07-20 10:52:46.522      933-951/? W/System.err﹕ at android.os.RecoverySystem.installPackage(RecoverySystem.java:337)
```

I had tried all permissions that were required but I couldn't proceed.

So then since I was using API above 4.2 I tried to **put my app into `/system/priv-app`** and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

System apps (apps with shared user ID set to `android.uid.system`) cannot install system updates on Android 5 and newer - it's forbidden by a SELinux policy. To be specific writing to `/cache` is forbidden for system apps. In other words:

- `/cache` is owned by `system` user so your app running under `system` UID can write to it. *But only if SELinux is disabled/permissive.*
- If you have `android.permission.ACCESS_CACHE_FILESYSTEM` platform signature permission, you can write to `/cache`.

You'll need to remove the shared user ID. You still have to sign the app with platform signature and ensure you have the following permissions:

- `android.permission.REBOOT`
- `android.permission.ACCESS_CACHE_FILESYSTEM` - to write to `/cache`
- `android.permission.RECOVERY` - required on API 21 to reboot to recovery

This will work on Kitkat and Lollipop+ alike.

Comment: I have included all three mentioned permissions but still can't write to `/cache`. Does SELinux always need to be permissive to be able to write to `cache` or those 3 permissions suffice?

Comment: If it's a SELinux policy issue you should see a [message](https://source.android.com/security/selinux/validate#reading_denials) in logcat. Is there enough space in your /cache? I've seen devices with minimal cache partition and you could only use /data for updates.

Comment: I believe there is enough space in my `/cache` since using `setenforce 0` solved the problem but I don't want to make SELinux permissive. I was asking if it's necessary to make SELinux permissive or there is another way to make it work without changing SELinux.

Comment: @mahdi did you ever figure out a way to make this work? I believe I have similar issue with an Android 9 system app update issue and I really don't want to disable SELinux entirely (and figuring out custom policies has proven very difficult....)

Comment: @GarryMcKee I wasn't able to fix the problem with system apps. As a work around, as mentioned in this answer, I removed `android.uid.system` from manifest.

Answer (score 0):

I have problem the same with you when create custom OtaUpdate app in **android 5.0.2** and i have resolved it. I will share with you with 2 steps below:

1. Add android:sharedUserId="com.google.uid.shared" in AndroidManifest.xml
2. Push your apk to system/app or system/priv-app

For **android 4.1.2** :

1. Add android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system" in AndroidManifest.xml
2. Push your apk to system/app

Comment: > Add android:sharedUserId="com.google.uid.shared" in AndroidManifest.xml

This will create issues if you have Google apps installed.

Just make sure that the app is in system/priv-app and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

**For Android 5.1.0**

1. Add `android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"` in AndroidManifest.xml
2. Push your apk to `system/priv-app`
3. and then

   ```
   adb root
   adb shell setenforce 0
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem in android 8.
If you add `android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"` in `AndroidManifest.xml`,
it should work.

Answer (score 0):

## create recovery.te (a13/14)

add /android_root/device/vendor/codename/sepolicy/private/recovery.te

```
# Set recovery to permissive
recovery_only(`
  permissive recovery;
')
```

example:

```
cat <<EOCONFIG >/android/device/xiaomi/taoyao/sepolicy/private/recovery.te
    # Set recovery to permissive
    recovery_only(`
      permissive recovery;
    ')
    EOCONFIG
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).