# Platform signed OTA updater app for android

Tags: java, android, android-source, custom-rom, android-firmware

Trying to build an app for updating android OS built from source. Even after signing the app with the platform key, the method `RecoverySystem.installPackage(context,file)` when applied on an updatefile placed in '/data/cache' gives error that writing to /cache is not permitted for the app. Also, an SElinux error is thrown for trying to access /cache partition.

The app holds the necessary permissions `android.permission.RECOVERY`, `android.permission.REBOOT` and `android.permission.ACCESS_CACHE_FILESYSTEM`

Going through the source code, the lines

```
...
FileWriter uncryptFile = new FileWriter(UNCRYPT_PACKAGE_FILE);
try {
    uncryptFile.write(filename + "\n");
} finally {
    uncryptFile.close();
}
...
```

in RecoverySystem.installPackage() triggers the error.
(http://androidxref.com/9.0.0_r3/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/RecoverySystem.java#562)

Even though the error is displayed, the device still reboots to apply update but the recovery shows "no command" screen most probably as no commands are written to /cache/recovery

the OS build is user build and thus not rooted.

am i missing something? is there any other way for a platform signed app to install firmware updates for the user build?

Similar : [Android development RecoverySystem.installPackage() cannot write to /cache/recovery/command permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15123742/android-development-recoverysystem-installpackage-cannot-write-to-cache-recov)